# Static front page for seo yoast or header.php?

Tags: html, wordpress, static, seo

I clicked reading -> choose static front page! I want static page on homepage! I made one new page on homepage and topic cheap web hosting india on page or home topic?  But I m confused for yoast seo and `header.php`

That page will appear topic keyword - cheap web hostjng india on google search?

Need seo or `header.php`?
Will I add title and meta from yoast seo?
or
will I add to write meta description and title and keyword on `header.php`?
Or
Both will I add both title and meta from seo and add meta description and title on `header.php`? Solve me?

Answer (score -1):

That's how this will work. If you are using totally html based static page then you have to provide your title and meta information by your self, on the other hand if you are using theme based static page then your title and meta information will be coming from your yoast SEO plugin and will be inserted inside `header.php` page automatically and you have no need to worry about it.

Comment: I see "You can determine the title and description for the front page by editing the front page itself »" and go to Pages > select the Home page and click edit when you scroll down at the bottom you will see the Yoast menu and there should be a description and title field where you can enter your custom description. right?

Comment: Yes, you have to edit your page in dashboard and add your requored SEO related details inside relevant yoast fields. That's all